# How can I set the sample rate for Audio?

Tags: audio

I'm using Blender (v2.72) to do some video editing. I record some voice audio at 96kHz and then drop it into the VSE to sync the audio to the scene. Once I make my cuts, I render just the audio to do further post processing.

Every time I render only the audio, it keeps coming out as 44.1kHZ. I want it to be exported as 96kHz. So how do I do this?

When I go into User Preferences, I have the following selected:

- OpenAL
- Channels: Stereo
- Mixing Buffer: 4096
- Sample Rate: 96kHz Sample
- Format: 24bit Signed.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but you can also set the Audio samplerate in the scene settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The control for audio Sample Rate is in Scene settings>Audio>Rate:

[image]